# Remove headers from openfeign request set by default http client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am calling an API, that blacklists certain HttpHeaders including `Content-Length` which seems to be preset by the HttpClient underneath spring-openfeign.
To properly receive an API response, I'd need to remove the `Content-Length` header.

The following workarounds had been tried:

- I tried to set the header to null or an empty String using the available Feign annotations `@Headers`, `@RequestHeaders`
- I implemented a `RequestInterceptor` that creates a copy of the available (immutable) header map, deletes the blacklisted header and sets the Map as `requestTemplate.headers(newHeaders)`. But only new headers can be added and the available ones not modified (seems to be really immutable ;))
- I researched on overriding the used HttpClient but wasn't successful until now.

Experienced errors/ issues:

The API I am calling returns a 400 based on their header schema validation.

Code:

In case any code-snippets are needed, I am happy to provide them but to me the issue does not seem to be related to any code issue as I am not  running into any exceptions.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Http Client included in `feign-httpclient` will **always** set the content length header if there is a request body present.  One way to address this to configure the Apache Client directly and provide it to Feign via the builder:

This custom client can have an Apache Http Client interceptor applied that allows you to modify the request after it leaves Feign and before Apache sends it.  Review [their javadoc](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.4.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor.html) for more information.

```java
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom.build();
    GitHub github = Feign.builder()
                     .client(new ApacheHttpClient(httpClient))
                     .target(GitHub.class, "https://api.github.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that one too. Unfortunately, the `Content-Length` will be added by the ApacheClient as well. In the meantime, I believe that it is always added to requests when there is a request body. And to be honest, to me thats a valid behavior for all requests and I'd blame the producer API for not developing against standards...

Answer (score 0):

FeignClient will preset Content_Length in the request header. In a keep-alive connection mode, either Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field must be set to signal the presence of a message body, so you can set Transfer-Encoding=chunked and Content-Length will be ignored by the serverside.

You can refer to [rfc7230#section-3.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.1)

> "The presence of a message body in a request is signaled by a
> Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field.  Request message
> framing is independent of method semantics, even if the method does
> not define any use for a message body."
>
> "In order to remain persistent, all messages on a connection need
> to    have a self-defined message length (i.e., one not defined by
> closure    of the connection), as described in Section 3.3.  A server
> MUST read    the entire request message body or close the connection
> after sending    its response, since otherwise the remaining data on a
> persistent    connection would be misinterpreted as the next request.
> Likewise, a    client MUST read the entire response message body if it
> intends to    reuse the same connection for a subsequent request."

and from [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) , you can read:

> "All HTTP/1.1 applications that receive entities MUST accept the
> "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6), thus allowing this mechanism
> to be used for messages when the message length cannot be determined
> in advance.
>
> Messages MUST NOT include both a Content-Length header field and a
> non-identity transfer-coding. If the message does include a non-
> identity transfer-coding, the Content-Length MUST be ignored.
>
> When a Content-Length is given in a message where a message-body is
> allowed, its field value MUST exactly match the number of OCTETs in
> the message-body. HTTP/1.1 user agents MUST notify the user when an
> invalid length is received and detected."